How to change a HTML button value
I want to change anything that says "Contact Me" to "Contact Us". I found some examples online they require either finding the ElementID or etc. I'm stumped on how I can achieve these. Can someone point me in the right direction?
I found examples like the below that use the ElementID but I can't find such thing for the button.
let text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");

I looked at trying to use an example like following, but I think its just completely wrong.
let originalString = "Contact Me";
let newString = originalString
.replace("Contact Me", "Contact Us");
console.log(newString);

Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Why not just search and replace in the IDE?

Best approach is to edit/update HTML. On your code Editor, you can search for all occurances of "Contact Me" and replace them with "Contact Us"

So we first define two constants searchString and replacementString. searchString contains the text we want to find in the document(Contact Me), and replacementString contains the text we want to replace it with(Contact Us).
The function replaceText() will recursively traverse through the DOM to find text nodes and input elements. This is what it does:

checks if the passed node is a text node or an element node

if it's a text node, it converts both the search string and the node content to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison

it checks if the lowercase node content contains the lowercase search string

if it does contain the search string, it replaces the text while preserving the original case

if it is an element node, it checks if the element is an <input> element and if its value matches the search string

if it does match the search string, it replaces the input value with the replacement string

after processing the current node, it recursively calls itself for each child node of the current node

it starts the process by calling replaceText() with document.body as the initial node, which initiates the traversal of the entire document body so it covers the entire HTML page


// Define the string you want to search for and the replacement
const searchString = "contact me";
const replacementString = "Contact Us";

// function that will replace text content of text nodes
function replaceText(node) {
  // if the node is a text node
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    // convert both search string and node content to lowercase for case-insensitive comparison
    const nodeContent = node.nodeValue.toLowerCase();
    const search = searchString.toLowerCase();
    // check if the lowercase node content contains the lowercase search string
    if (nodeContent.includes(search)) {
      // replace the text while preserving the original case
      const originalText = node.nodeValue;
      const newText = originalText.replace(new RegExp(search, 'gi'), function (match) {
        // preserve the case of the matched substring
        return match.charAt(0) === match.charAt(0).toUpperCase() ? replacementString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + replacementString.slice(1) : replacementString;
      });
      // update the text content of the node
      node.nodeValue = newText;
    }
  }
  // if the node is an element node
  else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    // check if the element is an input element and if its value matches the search string
    if (node.tagName === 'INPUT' && node.value.toLowerCase() === searchString.toLowerCase()) {
      // replace the input value with the replacement string
      node.value = replacementString;
    }
    // recursively call replaceText() for child nodes
    for (let i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      replaceText(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}
// start traversing the document body to find and replace text
replaceText(document.body);


You should just search and replace the text in the IDE or text editor. You should not need to do this via Javascript at all. Search for the phrase "Contact Me" in your text editor. Before replacing it, make sure it wrapped in either button tags to link tags i.e.
<button>Contact Me</button>

OR
<a>Contact Me</a>


Don't really know why you would want to do it this way but, the key is to use a regex to find all variations you want to change.


// regex will match only the "me"(s) after a "contact" separated by whitespace or a non-breaking-space, case-insensitively
const searchPattern = /(?<=contact(\s|&nbsp;)*)me/gi
// function that replaces each letter of "me" with matching case "us"
const swapUsForMe = me => me.replace('M', 'U').replace('m', 'u').replace('e', 's').replace('E', 'S');

document.querySelectorAll('body > *').forEach(el => {
  if ('SCRIPT' !== el.tagName.toUpperCase()) {
    if ('input' === el.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
      el.value = el.value.replace(searchPattern, swapUsForMe)
    } else {
      el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(searchPattern, swapUsForMe)
    }
  }
})
<h1>Contact ME!!</h1>
<p>
  Contact me with any questions
  <button>Contact&nbsp;me</button>
  <input type="button" value="ContactMe">
</p>

<input type="button" value="contact me">
<input type="submit" value="contact Me">
<input type="text" name="subject" value="contact me">




I see your web using wordpress, maybe it use some contact plugin and its better to change in wordpress instead modify with script. But, you can try this code for this moment:
<script type="text/javascript">    
    const buttonToChange = document.querySelector('input[value="Contact Me"]');
    buttonToChange.value = "Contact Us";
</script>


By going through your question, I understand that you are trying to get a phrase from the element (with id:demo) and change it.
Example:
original: I am working in Microsoft.
changed: I am working in W3Schools.
If your id name is correct, then check for the method told by @neurariefhs.
ie,
<script type="text/javascript">    
    let button = document.querySelector('input[value="the text in your button"]');
    button.value = "to text";
</script>

